# Cloudwatch for Memory and Diskspace for multiple ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I need to configure Memory and Diskspace alarms for multiple ec2 instances,i found one option "across all instances" but in there i did not find memory and Diskspace metrics.so do i need to create alarms for each instances separately?

I tried "across all instances" options ,but it did not show memory or diskspace metrics.

NA

need one alarm each for memory,cpu,diskspace for multiple ec2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

It is not showing any metrics because, first, you need to publish those metrics to Cloudwatch. To publish metrics to Cloudwatch, you will need to install Cloudwatch agent on each instance and use cron to schedule those scripts.

Here you can find more info on how to send RAM and Diskspace metrics to Cloudwatch:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html#mon-scripts-systems

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put it in proper context. I have all the metrics showing in cloudwatch, I actually used cloud watch unified agent (not scripts). So I have memory, disk, cpu metric now I need to set up alarms for those. I have 100 ec2 machines now do I need to set up 3*100 (disk, cpu, memory) alarms or only 3 alarm for all 100 ec2 machines. Also any links for steps would be appreciable.